# Convergence of an infinite sequence of Bernoulli trails

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $X_n\sim \operatorname{Bernoulli}(p)$ for all $n \geq1$. I have to discuss how this sequence converges in law, probability, a.s., as $n$ goes to infinity as a function of $p$. But this sequence doesn't converge to anything, right? What is meant here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you mean $X_n$ are independent random variables, with identical distribution  Bernoulli($p$) for all $n \geq 1$. I will assume $X_n \in \{0, 1\} \subset \mathbb{R}$, and first take $p\in(0,1)$.

1. Law($X_n$) = $\mu$ for all $n \geq 1$, so $X_n$ converges in Law. More precisely, for any bounded continuous function $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, we have $E[f(X_n)] = \int f(x) \mu(dx)$, which is independent of $n$, and $X_n \Rightarrow X_1$.
2. $X_n$ does not converge in probability to any random variable $Y$, because if $|X_n - Y| < 1/2$ for some fixed $n \geq 1$, then $X_n = Y$, and with probability $2p(1-p)>0$ we have $X_n \neq X_{n+1}$, thus $|X_{n+1} - Y| \geq 1/2$. Since $n$ was arbitary, there is no limiting random variable $Y$ in probability.
3. Since convergence almost surely implies convergence in probability, by 2. we cannot have a.s. convergence to any $Y$ either.

If $p = 0$ or $1$, the argument in 2. fails, and indeed we do have convergence in probability and almost surely (also to $X_1$).

Comment: Yes, thank you for the clarification! What would happen if we considered something like $\sin(\bar{X_n})/\sin(1-\bar{X_n})$? Where $\bar{X_n}$ is the sample average. And the $X_i$ are still Bernoulli.

Comment: By SLLN $\bar{X}_n \rightarrow p$ a.s. and by the continuous mapping theorem $f(\bar{X}_n) \rightarrow f(p)$ for any function $f$ (every function $f$ is continuous in the discrete topology on $\{0,1\}$).